# Hibernate:How to delete multiple rows in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried to delete multiple rows from database using **Hibernate**. Its successfully done.

When I refresh the .jsp page, the deleted items will shown again.

Here's my code:

```
public int deleteUserById(String id[])
{
  SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

  int flag = 0;

  User user;
  try
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
    {
      Session session = sf.openSession();
      session.beginTransaction();

      Long Id = Long.parseLong(id[i]);

      user = new UserRepository().getUserByID(Id);

      session.delete(user);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
      session.close();

    }
    flag = 1;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Error in deleteUserById=" + e);
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Other Method:

```
public User getUserByID(Long Id)
{
  SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
  Session session = sf.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();

  User user = null;

  try
  {
    user = (User) session.createQuery("from User where Id='" + Id + "'").list().get(0);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Error in getUserByID=" + e);
  }

  session.close();
  return user;
}
```

Getting User method:

```
public ArrayList<User> getAllUser()
{
  ArrayList<User> list_user = new ArrayList<User>();

  SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

  Session session = sf.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();

  try
  {
    list_user = (ArrayList<User>) session.createQuery("from User").list();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("Error in getAllUser=" + e);
  }

  session.close();
  return list_user;
}
```

I had used `session.clear()` but this doesn't solve the problem.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you updating the results on the bean ? or are you retrieving them again?

Comment: Did it get deleted in the database ?

Comment: Might be you html page rendered by JSP is getting cached on the browser.

Comment: @ArunM its deleted from db

Comment: So the problem is not with your hibernate code right ? The problem is with rendering the data. I think you need to hibernate along those lines and the  code in question is showing only your hibernate related code and not the rendering code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the user you fetch in getUserByID is queried in its own session which is closed and the user returned is detached. You should have one session per Request but you have nested sessions.

Try opening a session and a transaction at the beginning of the Request
and commit the transaction at the end and eventually close the session.

if you really want to use a session of it's own for querying, then you have to merge the detached result :

```
   user = session.merge(new UserRepository().getUserByID(Id));
```

**Note :** You are using many sessions and transactions in the for-loop in "deleteUserById" .... this is going to be rather resource consuming ... better  open the session and transaction around that loop.